# How does entity framework handle dates with a value of 0001/01/01

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-4.1

I am using the latest version of Telerik MVC extensions, ASP.NET MVC 3 with the Razor view engine, and Entity Framework 4.1 code first.

View model:

```
public class EditGrantApplicationViewModel
{
   // Other properties

   public DateTime HospitalisedFromDate { get; set; }
   public DateTime HospitalisedToDate { get; set; }
}
```

Controller action method:

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
   EditGrantApplicationViewModel viewModel = new EditGrantApplicationViewModel();

   return View(viewModel);
}
```

Create view:

```
<tr>
   <td valign="top"><label>From:</label></td>
   <td>@(Html.Telerik().DatePickerFor(x => x.HospitalisedFromDate)
         .Name("HospitalisedFromDate")
      )<br>
      @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.HospitalisedFromDate)
   </td>
   <td>&nbsp;</td>
   <td valign="top"><label>To:</label></td>
   <td>@(Html.Telerik().DatePickerFor(x => x.HospitalisedToDate)
         .Name("HospitalisedToDate")
      )<br>
      @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.HospitalisedToDate)
   </td>
</tr>
```

Grant application class:

```
public class GrantApplication
{
   // Other properties

   public DateTime HospitalisedFromDate { get; set; }
   public DateTime HospitalisedToDate { get; set; }
}
```

Context:

```
public class HbfContext : DbContext
{
   public DbSet<Bank> Banks { get; set; }
   public DbSet<AccountType> AccountTypes { get; set; }
   public DbSet<GrantApplication> GrantApplications { get; set; }
   public DbSet<AuditEntry> AuditEntries { get; set; }
}
```

Grant application table:

```
HospitalisedFromDate datetime null
HospitalisedToDate datetime null
```

I have a couple of questions regarding dates and how EF 4.1 code first handling dates.

When the view is loaded the first time, HospitalisedFromDate and HospitalisedToDate is initialised to 0001/01/01.  I don't have to select a date.  So if nothing is selected then it will try and insert 0001/01/01 into my database table.  And this is when I get an error:

**The conversion of a datetime2 data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.\r\nThe statement has been terminated.**

How would I fix this so that it adds a NULL value to the table column if nothing is selected?

Comment: Try using a nullable date instead `DateTime?` `public DateTime? HospitalisedFromDate { get; set; }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you know that the reason for this is because SqlDateTime min value and c# datetime min value are different. to have a nullable date time in c# you declare it like

```
public class EditGrantApplicationViewModel
{
   // Other properties

   public DateTime? HospitalisedFromDate { get; set; }
   public DateTime? HospitalisedToDate { get; set; }
}
```

by doing this the default value for the properties should now be null

**Edit:** just for more information declaring a nullable like that is equivalent to declaring it as

```
public class EditGrantApplicationViewModel
{
   // Other properties

   public Nullable<DateTime> HospitalisedFromDate { get; set; }
   public Nullable<DateTime> HospitalisedToDate { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Yes I do.  Shouldn't entity framework know that if it is the minimum date that it should add it as null?  Is this the only way to do it?

Comment: thats the only way to do it natively in EF and have it set to null in the database i think, without adding your own logic on save to switch DateTime.MinValue to SqlDateTime.MinValue or DBNull

Comment: WHat would be best practices?  Your way?  If I were to set it using SqlDateTime.MinValue will it add null in the database?

Comment: The best practice for a null in the database is to use a c# null which entity framework will convert to DB null when inserting into the database. Im not sure whether EF works natively with SqlDateTime.MinValue for nulls, i dont believe it will convert it to a null